# Android webview not work js function

Tags: java, android, webview

I use android webview, it loads the page and after loading the javascript function calls, but it does not work. For the test I ran alert function, it works well.

Settings webview:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new myJavaScriptInterface(), "CallToAnAndroidFunction");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        // chromium, enable hardware acceleration
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    } else {
        // older android version, disable hardware acceleration
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    webView.loadUrl("url");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // Make a note that the page has finished loading.
            authorization();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        }
    });

private void authorization() {
      webView.loadUrl("javascript:appReg(" + deviceId + "," + "promoCode);");
    }
```

Not work 
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:appReg(" + deviceId + "," + "promoCode);");

If call `webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('asd')");`, it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:appReg(" + deviceId + "," + "promoCode);");
```

need add '' `webView.loadUrl("javascript:appReg('" + deviceId + "," + "promoCode);'");`